# how to get users names using bluebird?

Tags: node.js, promise, q, bluebird

using bluebird q, I have this:

```
var myBill
db.getBillAsync().then(function (bill) {
myBill = bill
return users.find_user_by_idAsync(bill.user_id)
}).then(function (user) {
   myBill.user_name = user.name

console.log(myBill)

})
```

the purpose of the code above is to get the name of user and add it as to bill, this works well, now if I have a list of bills, how to get the names of all the bills and assign to myBills? using a loop? or bluebird has some other approaches?

```
var myBills
db.getBillsAsync().then(function (bills) {
  myBills = bills
  return users.find_user_by_idAsync(bill.user_id) ?
}).then(function (user) {
   ?
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will look something like this:

```
db.getBillsAsync().map(function (bill) {
  return users.find_user_by_idAsync(bill.user_id)
    .then(function (user) {
      bill.user_name = user.name;
      return bill;
    });
}).then(function (bills) {
// you got your bills with user names
})
```

Comment: thanks, but bill.user_name = user.name seems not referring to the 'bill' in map?

Comment: why? there is no other `bill` in the scope